# how to get distinct values from multiple columns in 1 single row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a row of data like this

```
id  first_cd    sec_cd  third_cd    fourth_cd   fifth_cd     sixth_cd
1   A           B           null        C           C            D
```

output should be :

```
id  first_cd    sec_cd  third_cd    fourth_cd   fifth_cd     sixth_cd
1   A           B       C           D           D               D
```

I need to get distinct values from the columns and remove nulls where there are.

if, first_cd...sixth_cd are columns on the same row.
1 A B null C C D are the values
Anyway to do in this in oracle sql

Comment: Please explain the logic behind.

Comment: Please provide more than one row of sample data and the output that you would expect from that data. Also please explain the logic in a bit more detail as it is currently not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use lateral joins:

```
select t.*, x.*
from t cross join lateral
      (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then cd end) as cd1,
              max(case when seqnum = 2 then cd end) as cd2,
              max(case when seqnum = 3 then cd end) as cd3,
              max(case when seqnum = 4 then cd end) as cd4,
              max(case when seqnum = 5 then cd end) as cd5,
              max(case when seqnum = 6 then cd end) as cd6             
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by n) as seqnum
            from (select t.cd1 as cd, 1 as n from dual union all
                  select t.cd2, 2 from dual union all
                  select t.cd3, 3 from dual union all
                  select t.cd4, 4 from dual union all
                  select t.cd5, 5 from dual union all
                  select t.cd6, 6 from dual 
                 ) x
            where cd is not null
           ) x
      ) x;
```

Note:  This returns the excess values as `NULL`, which seems more in line with your problem.